# Mocking Map in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have A class and inside I have defined a global ConcurrentHasMap . 
In one of the method I m putting the values inside the map . (that is called from some controller). In second method i m getting the values from that Map .

now How do i mock that map in junit ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you don't.

Maps are just that: containers. Sure, you can easily go

```
@Mock
ConcurrentHasMap whatever;

@InjectMocks
YourClassUnderTest underTest; 
...
```

but doing so is simply, conceptually: not a good idea.

You only mock things that you can't **control** in any other way. But a map, you can always check its *content* for example.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking data objects (Collections, DTO's) is usually not a good idea. Probably, if that's global Map, you can access it from your test class and just insert some values before or during test execution